# centos7 cockpit 176 can't add remote hosts

Tags: centos7, cockpit

I set up a 01-machines.json with one host (server0), I can ssh to server0 from the management node (master0). I get an error in the UI  saying `A compatible version of Cockpit is not installed on 192.168.66.17.`  It has the same exact version, so the error is misleading. I  can reach the UI on server0:9090 with the same creds (cockpit/***password***), no that isn't the password.

```
{
        "server0": {
          "address": "192.168.66.17",
          "visible": true,
          "color": "green"
      }
}
```

I don't see anything in the logs on master0 or server0 to see what is happening.  The user I  connect with in  the UI is the same on server0, it is in the wheel  group and has passwordless sudo

```
# ssh cockpit@192.168.66.17
cockpit@192.168.66.17's password: 
Last login: Wed Oct 24 14:16:18 2018 from 192.168.0.20
[cockpit@app-node-0 ~]$ sudo su -
Last login: Wed Oct 24 14:16:58 UTC 2018 on pts/1
[root@app-node-0 ~]#
```

Comment: I also don't see the Dashboard Tab I see in the howto guides out  there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, and solved with this:

In **master server**, I installed the dashoard.
In CentOS the you can install with:

```
sudo yum install cockpit-dashboard
```

This will enable the dashboard and allow you to add new server from dashboard UI.

---

In all other **servers**, you have to install the cockpit following the official doc:
[Official doc to install Dockpit](https://cockpit-project.org/running.html)

If you are running a centOS, just run:

```
sudo yum install cockpit

sudo systemctl enable --now cockpit.socket

sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=cockpit
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

After this, in dashboard on **master server** you will be able to add the new **server**

---

With this aproach, you don't need to use the /etc/cockpit/machines.d/ json files

Answer (score 2):

So, just installing cockpit doesn't include the dashboard, you need  to install cockpit-dashboard as well.

Comment: Did you get this working? I'm facing the same problem :/